# Which version of SQL Server Express gets installed with Search Server Express 2010?

Tags: search, installation, sql-server

What exact version of SQL Server Express 2008 gets automatically installed via the standalone setup of SSE 2010? Is it just SQL Server Express 2008, SQL Server Express 2008 R2 or a special kind of version (Windows Database Engine) like in previous editions?

If it's SQL Server Express 2008 R2, is it correct that the limit of a content db is now 10 GB instead of 4 GB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just installed SSE 2010 and it is SQL Sever Express 2008 SP1. (Build 10.0.2531.0)

So to avoid the 4 GB limit for content DBs I'd recommend to download and install SQL Server Express 2008 R2 and do a farm install instead of a single server install. This moves the limit to 10 GB.

If you can afford the license cost, it is also possible to use a full version of SQL Server 2008 together with SSE 2010. That would remove any content db limits.